# How can I tell if a string is 'correctly' encoded to Base64?

Tags: javascript, svg, base64, mandrill

I am trying to encode an SVG string to Base64 so I can send it over an AJAX call to an email provider as an attachment(*I am using [Mandrill](http://mandrillapp.com/docs/) as my email provider*):

For some reason it comes out wrong (*e.g SVG images are displayed by Gmail for example just fine, but when I receive it on my end, Gmail says the file is empty or broken*).

There's no possible way for me to know why.(basically I cannot debug anything without any guideline as to what is at fault).

> How can I check if my string is correctly encoded in Base64 format and
>   when decoded it will produce the original SVG drawing?

For the moment I encode using `window.btoa` and `escape` as this [example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64.btoa#Unicode_Strings) suggests.

**This is the code I use for encoding:**

```
base64SVG= window.btoa(encodeURIComponent(escape(svgString)));
console.log(base64SVG);
```

**This is my 'input' SVG string:**

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Ada-BlueDraw - http://github.com/dynamoRtc/Ada-BlueDraw/ -->
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5px" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
   <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="50" width="85" y="145" x="138.5" stroke="#4880FF" fill="#4880FF"/>
  <rect id="svg_2" height="159" width="193" y="89" x="177.5" stroke="#4880FF" fill="#4880FF"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

---

**And this is the Base64 string I am getting(*which is broken*):**

```
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
```

Comment: Yep, here it is: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html

Comment: `escape` or `encodeURIComponent` requires mandrillapp to decode them, else you end up with lots of %xy in `<svg>` text. The base64 string looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Mandrill docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method-send), the `content` property of an element of `attachments` is simply

> the content of the attachment as a base64-encoded string

There doesn't appear to be any requirement to use URI encoding; simply call `btoa` directly on the string you want to use as the attachment content. Don't use `escape` or `encodeURIComponent`.

The reason MDN recommends using `escape` is to encode characters with a character value above `255`. That's because `btoa` converts *binary values* into text characters. `btoa` assumes that *one character* in your input represents *one byte* of binary input. This is not always true, and in those cases, `btoa` throws an error.

In the case where one character requires more than one byte, the encoding and decoding mechanisms must agree on how to correlate bytes and characters. The MDN recommendation is to eliminate characters wider than one byte by running them through `escape`, and then reconstitute them on decoding using `unescape`.

However, Mandrill doesn't do this on decoding. They might do something different to map mutli-byte characters to multi-byte binary input, or they might not support it at all.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Edit to include musings on some more complicated concerns about base64 encoding for characters wider than one byte.

Comment: How can 1 character require more than 1 byte? I thought that all ASCII characters were 'equivalent' to 8bits=1byte. This was CS 101 when I was in college.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides "*How can 1 character require more than 1 byte?*" Are you suggesting that all printable characters can be mapped on to byte values? From there, we would conclude that your computer can only express 256 characters in text! To that I simply must say: `ϨϩϪϫϬϭϮϯϰϱϲϳϴϵ϶ϷϸϹϺϻϼϽϾϿЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐёђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџѠѡѢѣѤѥѦѧѨѩѪѫѬѭѮѯѰѱѲѳѴѵѶѷѸѹѺѻѼѽѾѿҀҁ҂҃҄҅҆҇҈҉ҊҋҌҍҎҏҐґҒғҔҕҖҗҘҙҚқҜҝҞҟҠҡҢңҤҥҦҧҨҩҪҫҬҭҮүҰұҲҳҴҵҶҷҸҹҺһҼҽҾҿӀӁӂӃӄ`.

Comment: well, maybe I wasn't paying attention to CS101.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides To explain a little further: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding range (and "extended ASCII" has an 8-bit range). ASCII is no longer widely used; it is useful as a way to remember UTF-8 unicode values, though, since the first 128 code points for UTF-8 are the same as the ASCII values. ([From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): "*UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064 valid code points in the Unicode code space*".) Text encoding is crazy-complicated, and I don't know enough to really explain it much further, other than to say it's very, very deep.

Comment: well, to end this, thank god I wasn't paying attention to that bit then. But I got curious now so I'll try to dip my head in the deep